# Get users email from twitter for auth (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json)

Tags: php, twitter, get, signature, php-curl

I followed the tutorial from twitter (documentation), and got stuck at the last stage when I need to get user data with his mail (to make user authorization).

When I make a request without parameters, I get user data such as name, user ID, etc., I need to get the user's mail, but when I add the parameter "? Include_email = true" I get the error 32 "We cannot authenticate you".

I do not understand where I made a mistake (as I understand in the signature)

Thanks for attention   
(Sorry for my English, this is not my native language)

```
    $oauthParams = [
        "oauth_consumer_key" => "...",
        "oauth_token" => $requestOauthToken,
        "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
        "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
        "oauth_nonce" => md5(uniqid()),
        "oauth_version" => "1.0",
    ];

    $baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true";
    $baseString = $this->buildBaseStringGET($baseURI, $oauthParams);

    $consumerSecret = '...';
    $compositeKey = $this->getCompositeKey($consumerSecret, $requestOauthTokenSecret);
    $oauthParams['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $compositeKey, true));

    $header = $this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauthParams);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $baseURI,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            $header,
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $response = json_decode($response, true)

private function buildBaseStringGET($baseURI, $oauthParams)
{
    $baseStringParts = [];
    ksort($oauthParams);
    foreach ($oauthParams as $key => $value) {
        $baseStringParts[] = "$key=" . urlencode($value);
    }
    return 'GET&' . urlencode($baseURI) . '&' . urlencode(implode('&', $baseStringParts));
}

private function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauthParams)
{
    $authHeader = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = [];
    foreach ($oauthParams as $key => $value) {
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . urlencode($value) . "\"";
    }
    $authHeader .= implode(',', $values);
    return $authHeader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not have an email address on their account, or if the email address is not verified, null will be returned.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials